# Why does the jQuery plugin Globalize reconize 9,999.99 in English local (en-CA) but not 9 999,99 in French local?

Tags: jquery, number-formatting, jquery-globalize

Why does Globalize `9,999.99` in English local (en-CA) but not `9 999,99` in French local (fr-CA). Is the space causing the problem in this scenario?

That happens when I call the numberParser method. NaN is returned if I enter `9 999,99` but that should be accepted since the formatter returns that.

Comment: Hey Rushino, sorry if my answer in the issue [#613](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/issues/613) wasn't clear. I've just replied in here in the hope it helps to get it clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer thinking-out-of-the-box: Because current Globalize lacks a parser feature called "Loose Matching" https://github.com/jquery/globalize/issues/292.

Short specific answer: Because space and no-break space are two different characters. The "space" of the fr-CA grouping separator isn't a regular space (bytecode 32 = hex 20), but it's a no-break space (bytecode 160 = hex A0). Try "sanitizing" your input with `input.replace( "\x20", "\xa0" )` before providing it to the parser as a workaround.

You can find detailed information at https://github.com/jquery/globalize/issues/288

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a fix planned ? (don't mind when just wanted to know if there was one planned)

Comment: value.replace(/ /g, '') work but your version doesn't any idea ? Also what mean xa0 ?

Comment: About a fix, currently no one showed interest in working on this feature, but I'd love to provide guidance for anyone that wants to (to start with what's in #292)...

Comment: About `.replace( "\x20", "\xa0" )` workaround, really? It should. Can you please try https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/4e83090a826162138d3f0a520d5fa6db? The \xa0 means a character which hex code is A0.

Comment: About `.replace( " ", "" )`, yeap good one, this should work too, because what it does is to remove the "invalid" grouping separator space. The parser is able to parse the number without the grouping separator.